# GLMM: Including a timepoints coefficient?

Tags: r, statistics, lme4, mixed-models

I have a question regarding the inclusion of a timepoint coefficient and I was wondering if you could help me.

I have my data setup like this:

| SUB | VarA | VarB | DV | Time2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

1. | 30   | 20   | 1   | 0
2. | 30   | 20   | 1   | 1
3. | 20   | 10   | 1   | 0
4. | 20   | 10   | 0   | 1
5. | 50   | 40   | 1   | 0
6. | 50   | 40   | 1   | 1

Where DV is my outcome measure at timepoint 1 & 2. I've then been suggested to include a Time2 variable in my model which signifies that its a separate timepoints. So my equation looks like this:

```
glmer(DV~Time2+VarA+VarB+(1|SUB), data=subset(dom_GNT3, is.na(VarA) +is.na(VarB)==FALSE),family="binomial",na.action=na.omit))
```

So this is including Time 2, VarA, and VarB as fixed effects and using sub as a random effect.

I then have results that look something like this:

| . | estimate | std. Error | Z value | Pr(>lzl) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Time2 | -12.461 | 6. | -2 | 0.004* |
| VarA | 6 | 3 | 1 | 0.001** |
| VarB | 7 | 2 | 1 | 0.182 |

My question rests with the Time2 point – Does inclusion in this model mean that significance at VarA and Time2 mean that there is a significant relationship between VarA and time1 as well as time2?

I'm a little confused on the interpretation for this variable inclusion!

Thank you!!!

Comment: You need to set up time as a repeated measures variable. Not sure about GLMM but other regression functions have cluster or strata functions so the within id variables like time can have a separate coefficient and error structure.

Comment: That said I’m not sure it matters. When you only have two time points.